# How to remove one class element at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile-application

If I have a series of elements with class="filler", how can I remove one at a time without removing all of them? And this is without giving them all ids; there are a LOT of them.

For example, say I have this:

```
<br class="filler"/>
<hr class="filler"/>
<br class="filler"/>
<hr class="filler"/>
<br class="filler"/>
<hr class="filler"/>
<br class="filler"/>
<hr class="filler"/>
```

This repeats for quite a ways. I would like to remove one br and one hr each time a function is called. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean "one at a time", and what does your markup look like?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('filler') will give you an array of all elements with specified class. You can access each with its  index. Not sure if it works with IE though.

Comment: Please provide code; one a time for example the first, or last, etc?

Comment: It depends, which one do you want to remove when the function is called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the first `br` and `hr` using jquery:

```
$("br.filler").first().remove();
$("hr.filler").first().remove();
```

Comment: Alternatively, `$("element:first").remove();` or `$("element").eq(0).remove();`, probably many others...

Comment: There's a .first()? Why is jQuery SO GREAT?

Comment: @Madmartigan: Using `:first` is an even better selector, but I've experienced problems with `:first` in IE8 and IE7, so I think `first()` is safer.

Comment: @AndersAbel: If what you say is true, make sure you file a [bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/newticket) so it can be fixed.

Comment: @Madmartigan: I'd first have to make sure that the problems isn't behind the keyboard (ie: I'm making something stupid), but once verified filing a bug is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$("br.filler").first().remove();
$("hr.filler").first().remove();
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/first/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Bongs/bnmzr/

HTML

```
Click on div to remove
<div class="filler"></div>
<div class="filler"></div>
<div class="filler"></div>
<div class="filler"></div>
<div class="filler"></div>
```

JS

```
//add the event on which you want to remove the div...
$(".filler").live("click", function(){
    $(this).remove();     //the div on which you click will be removed from DOM
})​
```

CSS

```
.filler
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 10px;
    width: 50px;
}​
```

you can play with the code... :)